# Adding images to Action-text trix editor on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trix

I am trying to insert a content attachment into the text, and when I enter it, in edit mode it shows it being there, but once i update the text, it does not save it.

here is what it looks like:
[this is the image going into the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qZja.png)
and then when i click update speech, it goes back to the original screen, without the images
[this shows the images wern't saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wXGw.png)

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.